# Regex to remove space between words in string

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive

I'm using Hive (Hadoop) to write an SQL-like statement.

I need to remove spaces in a field. For example, a postcode could be XX00 0XX and I'd like to remove the space before 0XX

So far, I have this regex:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(postcode, '[[:space:]]*', '')
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone advise?

Comment: If you are after removing *regular spaces*, and `REGEXP_REPLACE` works, you just need `REGEXP_REPLACE(postcode, ' +', '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would there be anything wrong with just doing a simple (non-regex) replace?  Try this:

```
REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '')
```

If your [version of Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) doesn't support `REPLACE()`, then you can use:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(postcode, '\\s+', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - sadly, REPLACE is not a valid function in Hive :(

Comment: @Kieran What version of Hive are you using?

Comment: Thank you for this the second one worked perfectly :) have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Did you try '[[:blank:]]*' 
Care as this will capture tabs as well.

Comment: Wrong regex dialect

Answer (score 0):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

**Translate**

```
select translate('XX00 0XX',' ','')
```

**regexp_replace**

```
select regexp_replace('XX00 0XX',' ','');
select regexp_replace('XX00 0XX','\\s','');
select regexp_replace('XX00 0XX','\\p{Blank}','');
select regexp_replace('XX00 0XX','\\p{Space}','');
select regexp_replace('XX00 0XX','\\p{javaWhitespace}','');
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

**replace**

```
select replace ('XX00 0XX',' ','')
```

(as of Hive 1.3.0 and 2.1.0).